# Ignore/unignore folders/files in TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, svnignore

The following webpage suggests that it is possible to unignore files/folders with TortoiseSVN by right-clicking the file/folder and select "remove from ignore list".  I do not have this option as shown below:

[image]

Also what is the difference between "Unversion add to ignore list" and "Unversion add to ignore list (recursive)"?  I have read on here that "Unversion add to ignore list (recursive)" ignores all files/folders in the tree, but in my experience "Unversion add to ignore list" does this as well.

Answer (score 15):

1. Right click on folder and go To properties. You will see list of all ignored files and externals.
2. Unversioned are the files which are either in source control nor in ignore [image: list]

Comment: just to advise, each folder have your own configuration, to see all files ingnored type on shell/cmd  `svn pg -R svn:ignore .`

Answer (score 5):

```
TortoiseSVN → Unversion and add to ignore list will first mark the file/folder for deletion from the repository, keeping the local copy.
It also adds this item to the ignore list so that it will not be added back into Subversion again by mistake.
Once this is done you just need to commit the parent folder.
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not see the `remove from ignore list` option because you did not open the context menu on an ignored file or folder. Your context menu is what you get when you right-click a *versioned* item (that's why you see an option to *unversion* it.) So start with a file or folder that is in your source controlled tree but is not itself source-controlled. Open the context menu there and you will see the option to remove it from the ignore list.

As far as the "recursive" option on ignoring an item, that likely means it will add the item to the svn:ignore property of the current directory and its child directories rather than just the current directory.